# Apply CSS to Anchor Tag of <ul> <il>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have existing CSS as

```
a:active {
    outline: none;
}
a:focus {
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

which works fine

i want to restrict the application only to those anchor items which are part of an `<ul><li>` item under a div with class="`tabs_container`"

so this is what i did only to fail !

```
#tabs_container ul li a:active {
    outline: none;
}
#tabs_container ul li a:focus {
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

am i doing it wrong ?

thanks in advance

**EDIT** 
My bad ! actually the ID="`tabs_container`" not Class.

Further reference : This is part of the tutorial about [How to create Tabs using Jquery from Scratch](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/10/how-to-create-tabs-with-css-an.html) by Erric Berry.

Comment: You'll want to change the #tabs_container to .tabs_container in your CSS if tabs_container is a class.

Comment: I hate it when i make simple errors like this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element has a class but you are trying to reference it with an ID

```
.tabs_container ul li a:active {
    outline: none;
}
.tabs_container ul li a:focus {
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i appreciate your answer but i made a typo. Plz see Edit

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

```
ul > li > a:active
```

This should catch anchors which are a child of `<li>` elements which in turn are children of `<ul>` elements.

Comment: Thanks ! But how do i restrict it to the anchors which are part of a class like "tabz" ?

Comment: If the div has the ID set then I think this should work: #tabs_container ul > li > a:active

Answer (score 1):

CSS classes are prefixed with a . (dot).

So, try

```
.tabs_container ul li a:active {
    outline: none;

}

.tabs_container ul li a:focus {
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```